# Disable Internet Explorer's "A proble‌m with this webpage caused Internet Explorer to close and reopen the tab"

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, internet-explorer

This has been a serious issue with me. Oftentimes I will be doing something very important in a webpage and it freezes up (I leave my PC on 24/7 and try to restart at least once a day or so but it is unavoidable). I would gladly sit back and wait for the webpage to finish doing whatever it is but Internet Explorer steps in and closes the webpage, losing all my precious work.

> A problem with this webpage caused Internet Explorer to close and reopen the tab.

I am using Internet Explorer 11 and have had this issue for a while now. Is there any way to disable this, **like** a registry hack to change the wait time for webpages or something? Switching to Chrome or Firefox is not really an option for me.

Comment: Just a guess that if IE closes the page, the problem wasn't just things taking too long.

Comment: Check all the add-ons (the gear/settings icon) for updated versions and/or disable them all. See if the behavior continues. If it does not, re-enable the add-ons one by one until it starts happening again. Java and Flash have been known to cause this. Also, if you have any "safe search" functionality in anti-virus etc, disable that to see if the problem goes away (these usually hook into the browser and do {magic} which can cause problems).

Comment: Does this happen when starting Internet Explorer in No Add-ons mode by, in the Run command, typing `iexplore.exe -extoff`.

Comment: You really can't disable this message, and it isn't time-based. That's some internal error handling in IE that's indicating an unrecoverable crash, and has bubbled up to a point that's informed the main browser window that it must reload the current URL. This kind of crash could be a bug in the rendering engine, a problem in the structure of a page, any one of a number of issues.

Comment: Besides starting Internet Explorer in No Add-ons mode, you could also have a look for interesting error messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Although my answer was honest, and I stand behind it despite the fact it was deleted, I will reiterate it here: Internet Explorer is telling you that the site you're using, whatever it may be, is interacting with IE in a way that is causing it to crash internally. The message you posted is IE's way of telling you this, effectively saying "I've crashed, and I even had to tear down the tab the site was on." When IE crashes in this way, there are *myriad* possible answers. What site? What were you doing or viewing? What other software/hardware is on your machine?

Comment: If the site you are visiting is a regular necessity and this behavior is recurrent, your next-best hope is to go to IE's Internet Options->Advanced tab->"Reset..." to completely reset Internet Explorer's settings to factory defaults, and see if this causes the troublesome site to behave differently. Other software, such as antivirus and firewall, can also contribute to this crash condition. I wish there were a magic bullet to solve your problem!

Comment: As @DavidW has said, there are very many possible reasons for this error and there is no one solution to fit them all, so some analysis is required. We cannot help you if you don't answer our questions.

Comment: @harrymc After running without addons I cant get it to crash, I think that my adblocker (adblock plus) is causing issues. That really stinks.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments on the post, I have advised trying to start Internet Explorer in No Add-ons Mode by entering in the Run command the following command:

```
iexplore.exe -extoff
```

In this mode, apparently the crash does not happen, so we can assume that some
add-on is responsible for this problem *in this case*.
In the general case, it should be remarked that there are very many possible
reasons for such a crash and that there is not one solution to fit them all.

You will now need to disable selectively add-ons until you find the one that
is crashing. Once found, you could :

1. Search for and install the latest version for the add-on
2. Do without the add-on
3. Search for an alternative add-on

Comment: The ad blocker is ad block plus and can be downloaded from the internet explorer add-ons page

Comment: https://adblockplus.org/en/internet-explorer

Comment: Right, I was off the mark there. It's entirely possible for an ad-blocker to cripple a page. Try to disable Adblock Plus every time you do something important, or for safer browsing use the No Add-ons Mode.

Comment: Ok that's a good idea, thanks for your help! Still no way to just disable the closing the tab huh. Well I guess I'll have to live with this. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting behavior: after turning off silverlight add-on, after surfing to my failingurl, IE redirects to `res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#<failingurl>` without resolving to anything, instead of refreshing the failingurl again...
On my device there are no other add-ons to be turned off though, and it still fails. I'll make sure to post back here whenever I find a solution...